# Error in reCaptcha implementation in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha

I am following this tutorial : http://www.sieena.com/blog/archive/2010/10/05/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-an-asp-net-site.aspx to implement reCaptcha in my ASP.net website from VS2010 ... but i am getting a error like this

[image]

What might I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed keys

> PublicKey="Your very own public key here" PrivateKey="Your very own
>   privat key here"

that you should get from your account?

Comment: no i didnot signup. because it was actually asking for a domain, which i dont have... i am just creating a sample login form... then what should i do?